# Ms-Access Functions to compare in Where clause condition for two memo RichText column || RichTextBox.Rtf gives different rtf tags

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access-2010, richtextbox, rtf

I building a Question&Answers application in **C#** *WinForms* where there will be four answers for each question on which the user will have select one and proceed.

Let's say: I have two tables with different columns.*Database* is `Ms-Access 2010`

```
Table1(userId,questionId,selectedAnswer)
Table2(questionId,question,correctAnswer,marks,opt1,opt2,opt3)
```

Table1 and Table2 columns are `memo(RichText)` datatype to store questions and answers except questionId,userId. I have selected `RichText` instead of `PlainText` because **Quest.&Answers** included different **mathematical** symbols which weren't supported by *PlainText* dataype and *Textbox* control in VisualStudio.

So,while creating **quest&answers** and displaying for selection to users, I have used *RichTextBox* control and insert content into *db* for *question creation* for *Table2* and for *the selectedAnswer* for *Table1* using

> richTextBox.Rtf property via OleDbCommand Parameters.

And in order to get the total marks i have use the following query.

`SELECT t1.userId,SUM(marks) As TotalMarks
FROM TABLE1 as t1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 as t2 ON t1.questionId=t2.questionId
WHERE t1.selectedAnswer=t2.correctAnswer
GROUP BY t1.userId`

This query worked fine for the `memo(PlainText)` datatype and using `TextBox` control in VS but not for `memo(RichText)`.
Because sometimes *RichTextBox.Rtf* gives value which

> *starts* as  `{\rtf1\ansi\` and sometimes starts likes `{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\`
>   for the *same* content in RichTextbox

So the *correctAnswer* and *selectedAnswer* field in db get different rtf value/tags for the same content.

> This is a problem where we have to compare in where clause in above query `where t1.selectedAnswer=t2.correctAnswer`

So.

1. Is there a *ms-access function* which will give only the actual content of the rtf value. Such as *Year function* which give only the *year* parts. So, we can use sth. such as `function(t1.selectedAnswer)=function(t2.correctAnswer)` in above query.
2. Or is it better to create *another memo(Plaintext)* column for the *corresponding memo(RichText)* column so we can *compare two Plaintext field* in where clause which will work fine.
3. Or the process i am doing is not dependable and there is a better way to accomplish it.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Don't your `RichTextBox` feature a `Text` property for exactly this ...?

Comment: @Gustav: `Text` property gives only the _text_ and does not support _rich text_ such as mathematical symbols and others etc. And this application needs to support richText for both _Questions and Answers_. 
I found solution by creating `memoPlainText datatype` for the corresponding _required memoRichText_ column but I think this is no _dependable_ + _dataRedundancy_ in db too.

Comment: Oh, so you need to compare the formulas. I missed that.

Comment: @Gustav: Yes, in _Where_ clause to sumUp marks based on _correctAnswer=selectedAnswer_ but _RichTextBox_ generates different starting tags for the same content like `{\rtf1\ansi\`   (correct one, i guess) or sometimes   `{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\`   (incorrect, i think). Though the _correctAnswer_ and _selectedAnswer_ is same, the marks weren't add up because of different starting tags. So i thought there would be `Ms-Access function` to extract `Text` only or some better ways to do the process.

Comment: No, Access can only handle RTF via the old ActiveX RichText Control and that was only up to version 2003. Version 2007 and forward implements "rich text" by an HTML control which, of course, has nothing to do with RTF. You can in Access create VBA code using the ActiveX control that extracts plain text from a field encoded with RTF, but I guess it will be identical to what you currently can extract with the `Text` property.

Comment: @Gustav : I am sorry i don't anything about the VBA,ActiveX control etc. RTF itself is new for me sir. But anyway Thank your for ur reply sir.

Answer (score 0):

> a better way to accomplish it

You could avoid the hassles of comparing RTF text by storing the answers in a separate table with a numeric ID (primary key), something like

```
AnswerID  QuestionID  CorrectAnswer  AnswerText
--------  ----------  -------------  -----------------------
       1           1  No             Answer 1 for Question 1
       2           1  No             Answer 2 for Question 1
       3           1  Yes            Answer 3 for Question 1
       4           1  No             Answer 4 for Question 1
       5           2  No             Answer 1 for Question 2
       6           2  Yes            Answer 2 for Question 2
       7           2  No             Answer 3 for Question 2
       8           2  No             Answer 4 for Question 2
```

Then you could just store the numeric ID of the answer (instead of the answer text) for each [respondent + question].

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I have already get solution by adding extra text column though it's not the best. For ur suggestion, for me, it would be troublesome to create another table and do join and manipulate those tables. But can u provide simple db design for ur suggestion related to above app...